# How to prevent ArrayOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a `GridLayout` filled with `JButton`. When I press a button, I want to de-activate all buttons except those adjacent to the `JButton` clicked. I have this code:

```
btnLetter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < tab.length; j++) {
                                tab[i][j].setEnabled(false);
                                for (int ii = 0; ii < tab.length; ii++) {
                                    for (int jj = 0; jj < tab.length; jj++) {
                                        if (tab[ii][jj] == (JButton) e.getSource()) {

                                            tab[ii][jj + 1].setEnabled(true);
                                            tab[ii + 1][jj + 1].setEnabled(true);
                                            tab[ii + 1][jj].setEnabled(true);
                                            tab[ii - 1][jj].setEnabled(true);
                                            tab[ii - 1][jj + 1].setEnabled(true);
                                            tab[ii - 1][jj - 1].setEnabled(true);
                                            tab[ii][jj - 1].setEnabled(true);
                                            tab[ii + 1][jj - 1].setEnabled(true);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: what is the value of `ii - 1` when `ii` == `0`? Use `for/each` loops and you won't have these kinds of `one off errors`!

Answer (score 1):

You must handle the case in which the clicked button is on the first/last row/column, in which case adding/subtracting one may bring you out of the array bounds.

For example, before calling `tab[ii + 1][jj + 1].setEnabled(true)`, you must verify that `ii < tab.length-1` and `jj < tab.length-1`.

Comment: What I want to do is to desactivate all button except the adjacent ones, so if I click on the button tab[0][0], I want tab[0][1], tab[1][0] and tab[1][1] to be activated.